# Font settings for OS X on a large screen TV

Tags: macos, hdtv

I am running a Mac Mini with OS X 10.6.2 as a HTPC on a 42" 1080p TV

With Windows 7 it was trivial to make everything easier to read from the couch (icons, web browser, explorer etc). Is there a simple way to achieve the same goal on OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy way to do this in System Preferences. [This post](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10050205#10050205) describes a method using the following command in the Terminal:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleDisplayScaleFactor 1.5
```

where 1.5 is a scaling factor you'll need to play around with. It will apply to newly opened applications. It may not change *every* font for *every* application, though.

Comment: No problem. Good to hear.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only native part of OS X designed to be used on a TV is FrontRow (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd>), unfortunately.

Comment: Hulu and XMBC (plays DVDs too) work well on a TV too. FrontRow seemed a little lame to me. Last night I was using ctrl + scroll wheel to zoom in on Safari

Comment: Oh, if you don't mint zooming, then the universal access zooming is the most awesome zooming ever!

Comment: I just played with the settings and found it possible to zoom the task bar + finder icons. That's all I've found so far

Comment: Have a look at the universal access preferences, you can enable zooming with Ctrl+scroll, and then the whole screen zooms and follows the mouse, it's awesome :D

Comment: good tip, will do