# Reducing font size of Mac OS X menu bar?

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increasing System Menu Font Size for OS X Lion](https://superuser.com/questions/328849/increasing-system-menu-font-size-for-os-x-lion)

Is there a way to reduce the font size of the menu bar across the screen in a Mac OS X? I tried TinkerTool, but that didn't do what I wanted it to do.

I'm already at maximum resolution.

Comment: You can do this globally using the `AppleDisplayScaleFactor` variable described in [a previous answer of mine](http://superuser.com/questions/88308/font-settings-for-os-x-on-a-large-screen-tv/90299#90299). I haven't tried it, though, so let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Also check out [this Macworld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/142173/2009/08/scaleapps.html).

Comment: Setting the scale factor doesn't work as of Lion.

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/328849/increasing-system-menu-font-size-for-os-x-lion) question/answer may help.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Look at this different question: [Increasing System Menu Font Size for OS X Lion](http://superuser.com/questions/328849/increasing-system-menu-font-size-for-os-x-lion)