# Increasing System Menu Font Size for OS X Lion

Tags: osx-lion

My father-in-law recently picked up an iMac (with OS X 10.7 - Lion) and loves it. However, his eyesight isn't that great and would like to find a way to increase the font size of the system menu bar like he could on his old Windows system.

I've been unable to find anything in the system configuration that might work. I've heard that the TinkerTool might be able to do it, but I'm a little hesitant to monkey around with his system - I don't want to introduce system stability issues.

**Question:** Has anyone been able to find any good way to increase the system menu font size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without introducing any software that may cause instability - especially since Lion is still new, you might want to look at reducing the resolution to a lower 16x9 setting. This way not only will the menu bar be larger, but text in applications and browsing will be larger. Since you are using a 16x9 resolution, the images on the screen will not appear stretched either.

Comment: This might work - I'll have to see if I can find a suitable 16:9 setting that doesn't make the display "fuzzy". Thanks!

Comment: "Fuzzy" will be a relative assessment - while it may be fuzzy to you, it might not to him so ask his opinion.

Comment: Fair enough - I'll ask him to try a lower resolution.

Comment: he decided he could live with the fuzziness. I personally would like it - but it works. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: typo - "wouldn't like it"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the menubar can not be changed, the system font sizes can be changed but the top menu bar has a fixed font size based on the screen resolution.

Another way to work around this is by having a magnifying glass on screen?

`System Preferences` > `Universal Access` > `Zoom -> On` > `Zoom In Window -> On`

But it's not really what you're looking for I guess.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this, but this wasn't a solution that he liked.

Answer (score -1):

Enable columns view in any window in Finder. Then just tap in a white area and select "Show View Options". At the pop up window change the font size.

Comment: -1, you probably haven't read the question. It's about increasing the size of the menu bar.